# QODBC Online linked server to SQL server has empty tables - no data

Tags: ssms, quickbooks, qodbc

I have a linked server from SSMS to Quickbooks through QODBC Online. I have run the QODBC Setup Screen and connected to the desired client. The query runs but returns no data. it shows all the column names but no data. am I missing a step?

created linked server. tested connection. run query. no results

Im able to connect and receive data through powerbi but nothing on sql server.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are able to query the table using QODBC Online Test Tool.
If you are using SQL Server 32-Bit, use the 32-Bit test tool. If you are using SQL Server 64-Bit, use the 64-Bit test tool.

If you cannot get the results in the test tool, please reset the QODBC Online Optimizer.
QODBC Online Setup Screen >> Optimizer >> Reset Optimizer.

If you can get the results in the test tool, the same SQL statement should also work in the SQL statement.

If you are still facing the issue, please raise a support ticket at https://support.qodbc.com